# Как перевести значение температуры?

Tags: json, java

Получаю значение температуры `"temp":276.15`. Как перевести в нормальный вид?

```
"main":{
"temp":276.15,
"pressure":1006,
"temp_min":276.15,
"temp_max":276.15,
"humidity":91
},
```

Comment: В Кельвинах, что ль? Ну, отнимите 273.

Comment: "dt":1412249400 ?

Comment: @Ильмир Сулейманов, это timestamp, количество секунд с 01.01.1970 00:00:00

Comment: Object date = (Object) mainJson.get("dt");
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp((long) date);
Date date2 = new Date(stamp.getTime());
System.out.println("Data = " + date2); 

//Возвращает ?  Data = Sat Jan 17 12:17:36 GMT+04:00 1970

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это температура в [Кельвинах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%E5%EB%FC%E2%E8%ED).

Чтобы перевести в Цельсии, надо отнять `273.15`.

Давление, походу, задано в гектопаскалях (в сотнях паскалей), а влажность - относительная.